How to generate multiple “views” (lists) of my theorems/axioms/definitions (with full content) while only writing them once in the main body?
I want my LaTeX document to have a single “main body” where I write my axioms, definitions, and theorems (each with their full text). Then, automatically, I need two additional sections, in the beginning:

“ASSIOMI” — listing only the axioms (in the order they appear) with
their entire content.
“STRUTTURA LOGICA” — listing axioms, definitions, and theorems all together, again in the order they appear in the main body, with
full content.

Finally, the main body itself should appear as usual, also with the same text (so I’m effectively printing each item multiple times but only writing it once in my source).
I’ve tried various approaches (e.g., thmtools, environ, etoolbox, capturing environments or macros) but can’t get a straightforward, single-pass solution that produces this exact layout:
ASSIOMI
(Axiom 1) <Content of axiom 1>
(Axiom 2) <content of axiom 2>
STRUTTURA LOGICA
(Axiom 1) <content of axiom 1>
(Definition 1) <content of definition 1>
(Axiom 2) <content of axiom 2>
(Definition 2) <content of definition 2>
...
MAIN BODY
... discussion that includes Axiom 1, Definition 1, Axiom 2, Theorem 1 ...
I only want to write the actual content once but display it in these three different places with the same text. Any code examples or suggestions would be appreciated!
Edit: this is what i got so far but it just writes the titles of the axioms, not also the content.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{thmtools}

% Define the environments: Axiom, Theorem, Definition
\declaretheorem[name=Axiom]{axiom}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[name=Definition]{definition}

\begin{document}

% 1) List of all axioms
\section*{List of all Axioms (in order of appearance)}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={axiom}]

% 2) List of Axioms, Definitions, and Theorems
\section*{List of Axioms, Definitions, and Theorems (in order of appearance)}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={axiom,definition,theorem}]

\section{Main Text}
Example text before introducing the environments.

\begin{axiom}[First Axiom]
Text of the **first axiom**.
\end{axiom}

\begin{definition}[First Definition]
Text of the **first definition**.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}[First Theorem]
Text of the **first theorem**.
\end{theorem}

\begin{axiom}[Second Axiom]
Text of the **second axiom**.
\end{axiom}

\end{document}



welcome! can you provide a minimal example? though I don't think a single-pass solution is possible if you want the auto-generated sections to precede the content they should contain. but it is hard to see why you need a single-pass solution. surely other aspects of your document require multiple passes?

thank you :) i added what i got so far. Maybe the single pass is not essential, if it's necessary to make it work.

The store-all option and print-body list key of keytheorems are designed to do exactly this (disclaimer, I wrote the package). However, it's impossible to do what you want in a single pass since the theorems' content needs to be written to an external file.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[store-all]{keytheorems}

% Define the environments: Axiom, Theorem, Definition
\newkeytheorem{axiom}
\newkeytheorem{theorem}
\newkeytheorem{definition}

\begin{document}

% 1) List of all axioms
\listofkeytheorems[
  ignoreall,
  show={axiom},
  print-body,
  title={List of all Axioms (in order of appearance)},
  ]

% 2) List of Axioms, Definitions, and Theorems
\listofkeytheorems[
  ignoreall,
  show={axiom,definition,theorem},
  print-body,
  title={List of Axioms, Definitions, and Theorems (in order of appearance)},
  ]

\section{Main Text}
Example text before introducing the environments.

\begin{axiom}[First Axiom]
Text of the **first axiom**.
\end{axiom}

\begin{definition}[First Definition]
Text of the **first definition**.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}[First Theorem]
Text of the **first theorem**.
\end{theorem}

\begin{axiom}[Second Axiom]
Text of the **second axiom**.
\end{axiom}

\end{document}



Thank you so much! This is exactly what i was looking for :)
